# A Picker controller similar to UIImagePickerController to pick files ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uidocumentpickervc

Just as we have *`UIImagePickerController`* to pick images into our iOS app. Is there a way to import the files in a similar manner as well? *`iOS 8`* suggests a *`UIDocumentPickerViewController`*, but only for files in iCloud. Is there a way to import files in *`iOS 7`*?

Thanks!

Kaushil Ruparelia

Comment: What kind of files are you talking about? Because of the sandbox you are only allowed to read files in your own app sandbox. Normally the only interesting ones are that which the user created with your app or downloaded it with your app or whatever. All this files must be stored in the Document directory of your apps sandbox. So there is no need for a picker. You can just show the contents of this directory in a table view (f.e.) and let the user pick one.

Comment: Files like the .txt and the .pdf. The way we are allowed to view the pictures and videos isn't there a way to get the URLs of those files as well?

Comment: No it isn't because there is no interchangeable directory every App can access. Thats the price we have to pay for the much more secure operating system. (I love it, that i must not think about installing a virus scanner on my phone)

Answer (score 1):

iOS 8 allows you `UIDocumentPickerViewController` for picking files on iCloud. Other file inside your iDevice could not load or find with this controller.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
for (NSString *s in fileList){
    NSLog(@"%@", s);
}
```

You can access files from your App Sandbox, and Some other type like, Images/Videos through `UIImagePickerViewController`.

In short, There is no way to get other files directly through any controller :(

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: Yeah i know :(. Lets hope some one finds a way in the future versions and answers this. ;-)